# Linq to SQL - Failing to update

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm having some troubles with updating linq to sql entities.
For some reason, I can update every single field of my `item` entity besides *name*.

Here are two simple tests I wrote:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void TestUpdateName( ) {
            using ( var context = new SimoneDataContext( ) ) {
                Item item = context.Items.First( );

                if ( item != null ) {
                    item.Name = "My New Name";
                    context.SubmitChanges( );
                }
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestUpdateMPN( ) {
            using ( var context = new SimoneDataContext( ) ) {
                Item item = context.Items.First( );

                if ( item != null ) {
                    item.MPN = "My New MPN";
                    context.SubmitChanges( );
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, TestUpdateName() fails with the following error:
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'..`

And here's the outputted SQL:

> UPDATE [dbo].[Items] SET  WHERE ([Id]
>   = @p0) AND ([CategoryId] = @p1) AND ([MPN] = @p2) AND ([Height] = @p3) AND
>   ([Width] = @p4) AND ([Weight] = @p5)
>   AND ([Length] = @p6) AND
>   ([AdministrativeCost] = @p7)
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
>   -- @p1: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
>   -- @p2: Input VarChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [My New MPN]
>   -- @p3: Input Decimal (Size = 0; Prec = 5; Scale = 3) [30.000]
>   -- @p4: Input Decimal (Size = 0; Prec = 5; Scale = 3) [10.000]
>   -- @p5: Input Decimal (Size = 0; Prec = 5; Scale = 3) [40.000]
>   -- @p6: Input Decimal (Size = 0; Prec = 5; Scale = 3) [30.000]
>   -- @p7: Input Money (Size = 0; Prec = 19; Scale = 4) [350.0000]
>   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build:
>   3.5.30729.4926

As you can see, no update is being generated (SET is empty ...)
I have no clue why is this happening.

And already in advance ... YES, the table `Item` has a PK (Id).
*Thank you* in advance!

**Update:**
It appears that the error is caused by overriding GetHashcode().
This is my current implementation:

`return string.Format( "{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", Name, Id, UPC, AdministrativeCost).GetHashCode( );`

Comment: what happens if you modify Name and one other property? Does it update both or just the other property? Also in the generated code is the setter on Name firing the `PropertyChanged` event? I don't think the DataContext considers it a change unless the event is fired.

Comment: If I modify name and another property, only the other property changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like your DBML might be out of synch.  You should delete the tables and re-add them and try and run it again.

Just delete your `Items` table manually and re-add it.

**EDIT**:  Based on your edit, you should check out the following thread regarding `GetHashCode`.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/6cc6c226-f718-4b22-baad-dba709afe74b/

> .Net rules claim that GetHashCode()
>   and Equals() must always be
>   implemented in tandem.  Two objects
>   that are equal must have the same hash
>   code.
>
> Also, the combination of GetHashCode()
>   + Equals() forms the entity's concept of identity.  If you make it based on
>   field values (other than PK) then the
>   identity changes as you change the
>   fields. This is bad if L2S must lookup
>   other info in a dictionary based on
>   the entity's identity, and especially
>   if L2S needs to find an entity in its
>   identity cache!
>
> Advice: don't change the identity of
>   an entity.  L2S expects it to be based
>   on the object's natural (address
>   based) identity.

Comment: Just deleted the table Manually and it did not work.
I also tried again to sync it using Hugati tools, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Isaac Does `TestUpdateMPN` work and just `TestUpdateName` fail? This error seems to occur when the dbml definition of the table does not match the schema.

Comment: +1 for the GetHashCode() stuff. That turned out to be my problem. Trying to change a field used by GetHashCode() override.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the SQL being generated is not including the contents of the `SET` clause (notice that there is no `[Name] = @pXX` after `SET`). Are all of the properties (data type, size, etc.) of the entity field set correctly in the dbml designer?

Comment: I paid attention to that and I edited the post a minute ago.
The properties on the DBML seem to be correct.

I use Hugati DBML tools to maintain my DBML schema in sync with the database.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Isaac: The latest version still reflects this problem (it says `UPDATE [dbo].[Items] SET WHERE...`). L2S is not generating a list of columns to update and the values that go with them (you would expect it to say `UPDATE [dbo].[Items] SET [Name] = @p0 WHERE...` or something similar).