# LinqToSQL Update: One Statement Per Changed Property

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

When I try to update a LinqToSQL Object, the engine creates one entry in `DataContext.getChangeSet().Updates` for each property I change.
This obviously fails due to overwrite checks...

How can I correct this behaviour (one update for all changes)?

As you can see in the generated SQL code, the properties ahvNo and insuranceNo are not recognised as changed (not in update list), but they have changed (in where query).

The first statement runs successfully, but the second one throws the exception `1 of 2 updates failed.`.

Here is the VB code I use:

```vb
Using dc As New WatchStoreDC()
    Dim usr = If(dc.users.SingleOrDefault(Function(u) u.id = id), New AppUser())
    usr.employeeNo = employeeNo
    usr.ahvNo = dc.formatAHVNumber(ahvNo)
    usr.insuranceNo = dc.formatInsuranceNumber(insuranceNo)
    usr.badgeNo = badgeNo
    usr.birthdate = birthdate
    usr.lastName = lastName
    usr.firstName = firstName
    usr.title = title
    usr.roles = roles

    Dim usrAct = String.Empty, mdfTim = Now
    If usr.id = 0 Then
        usrAct = "ins" : usr.createdAt = mdfTim : usr.createdByID = GeneralInfo.userID : dc.users.InsertOnSubmit(usr) : dc.SubmitChanges()
    Else
        usrAct = "upd" : usr.modifiedAt = mdfTim : usr.modifiedByID = GeneralInfo.userID
    End If

    Dim prf = If(usr.profile, New AppProfile())
    prf.languageID = profileLanguage
    prf.cultureID = profileCulture
    prf.updatedAt = mdfTim

    If prf.id = Guid.Empty Then prf.id = usr.securityID : dc.profiles.InsertOnSubmit(prf)
    dc.SubmitChanges()
End Using
```

This is the LinqToSQL schema:

```xml
<Table Name="app.tblUsers" Member="users">
    <Type Name="AppUser">
        <Column Name="usrID" Member="id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
        <Column Name="usrSecurityID" Member="securityID" Type="System.Guid" DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
        <Column Name="usrCompanyCode" Member="companyCode" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(25)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrEmployeeNo" Member="employeeNo" Type="System.String" DbType="Char(6)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrAHVNo" Member="ahvNo" Type="System.String" DbType="Char(14)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrInsuranceNo" Member="insuranceNo" Type="System.String" DbType="Char(16)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrTitle" Member="title" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(10)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrLastName" Member="lastName" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
        <Column Name="usrFirstName" Member="firstName" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(50)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="usrRole" Member="rolesInt" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
    </Type>
</Table>
```

This is the generated SQL:

```sql
UPDATE [app].[tblUsers]
SET [usrModifiedBy] = @p14, [usrModifiedAt] = @p15
WHERE ([usrID] = @p0) AND ([usrSecurityID] = @p1) AND ([usrCompanyCode] IS NULL) AND ([usrEmployeeNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrAHVNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrInsuranceNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrTitle] IS NULL) AND ([usrLastName] = @p2) AND ([usrFirstName] = @p3) AND ([usrLanguage] IS NULL) AND ([usrBirthdate] IS NULL) AND ([usrAddressStreetNo] = @p4) AND ([usrAddressAddLine] IS NULL) AND ([usrAddressZIP] = @p5) AND ([usrAddressCity] = @p6) AND ([usrAddressCountry] = @p7) AND ([usrPhoneWork] IS NULL) AND ([usrPhoneHome] = @p8) AND ([usrPhoneMobile] IS NULL) AND ([usrEMailWork] IS NULL) AND ([usrLogin] IS NULL) AND ([usrSiteLocation] IS NULL) AND ([usrSiteNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrUnitCenter] IS NULL) AND ([usrDepartment] IS NULL) AND ([usrOE] IS NULL) AND ([usrOEName] IS NULL) AND ([usrCostCenter] IS NULL) AND ([usrCCResponsible] IS NULL) AND ([usrSuperior] IS NULL) AND ([usrJoinDate] IS NULL) AND ([usrExitDate] IS NULL) AND ([usrExitReason] IS NULL) AND ([usrBadgeNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrContractType] IS NULL) AND ([usrContractTypeName] IS NULL) AND ([usrPayrollContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrHRContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrApprovals] = @p9) AND ([usrPaymentType] = @p10) AND ([usrRole] = @p11) AND ([usrEMailContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrPhoneContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrCreatedBy] = @p12) AND ([usrCreatedAt] = @p13) AND ([usrModifiedBy] IS NULL) AND ([usrModifiedAt] IS NULL) AND ([usrSignature] IS NULL) AND ([usrSignatureMIME] IS NULL)

UPDATE [app].[tblUsers]
SET [usrModifiedBy] = @p15, [usrModifiedAt] = @p16
WHERE ([usrID] = @p0) AND ([usrSecurityID] = @p1) AND ([usrCompanyCode] IS NULL) AND ([usrEmployeeNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrAHVNo] = @p2) AND ([usrInsuranceNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrTitle] IS NULL) AND ([usrLastName] = @p3) AND ([usrFirstName] = @p4) AND ([usrLanguage] IS NULL) AND ([usrBirthdate] IS NULL) AND ([usrAddressStreetNo] = @p5) AND ([usrAddressAddLine] IS NULL) AND ([usrAddressZIP] = @p6) AND ([usrAddressCity] = @p7) AND ([usrAddressCountry] = @p8) AND ([usrPhoneWork] IS NULL) AND ([usrPhoneHome] = @p9) AND ([usrPhoneMobile] IS NULL) AND ([usrEMailWork] IS NULL) AND ([usrLogin] IS NULL) AND ([usrSiteLocation] IS NULL) AND ([usrSiteNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrUnitCenter] IS NULL) AND ([usrDepartment] IS NULL) AND ([usrOE] IS NULL) AND ([usrOEName] IS NULL) AND ([usrCostCenter] IS NULL) AND ([usrCCResponsible] IS NULL) AND ([usrSuperior] IS NULL) AND ([usrJoinDate] IS NULL) AND ([usrExitDate] IS NULL) AND ([usrExitReason] IS NULL) AND ([usrBadgeNo] IS NULL) AND ([usrContractType] IS NULL) AND ([usrContractTypeName] IS NULL) AND ([usrPayrollContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrHRContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrApprovals] = @p10) AND ([usrPaymentType] = @p11) AND ([usrRole] = @p12) AND ([usrEMailContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrPhoneContact] IS NULL) AND ([usrCreatedBy] = @p13) AND ([usrCreatedAt] = @p14) AND ([usrModifiedBy] IS NULL) AND ([usrModifiedAt] IS NULL) AND ([usrSignature] IS NULL) AND ([usrSignatureMIME] IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching on google, I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017013/linq-to-sql-failing-to-update) which solved my problem.

The problem was as follows:
I was generating the hash code based on this properties.

I have now added a private variable to store the first generated hashcode.