# Why would Linq-to-SQL generate an Update statement that doesn't set any columns?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone

I've got a bit of code that updates a local cache of data, accessed via Linq-to-SQL on Windows Phone, that has code doing:

```cs
var ev = (from evt in context.Events where evt.EventId == e.EventId select evt).FirstOrDefault();
if (ev != null)
{
    ev.LastModified = e.LastModified; // In this case, a different DateTime
    ev.PublishStatus = e.PublishStatus; // In this case, PublishStatus.Deleted (numerically, 0);
    ev.Tags = e.Tags; // In this case, both are the same non-zero length string;
    // Some other properties are set to the same value, but omitted here for brevity
}
context.SubmitChanges();
```

This code is failing with:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException occurred
>     _HResult=-2147467259
>     _message=""
>     HResult=-2147467259
>     Message=There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = WHERE ]
>     Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>     ErrorCode=-2147467259
>     NativeError=25501
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>     InnerException:

Looking at the generated SQL below, I completely understand that the SQL is invalid, but I'm not understanding why it's not including the changes to the properties?

```sql
UPDATE [SpecialEvent]
SET 
WHERE [EventId] = @p0

-- @p0: Input Int32 (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [156305]
```

This *seems to have started* after a recent updated that added a column to the table (via: `dbUpdater.AddColumn<SpecialEvent>("Tags");` (where `dbUpdater` is of type `DatabaseSchemaUpdater`); this might be a red herring, though.

What can I do to find out why the columns being changed are not being included in the update statement?

Comment: In my case, a ["broken" implementation of `GetHashcode()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3017013/50447) was causing the issue